# Logo not printing properly with thermal printer flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I am trying to print a network image that is in the database using the thermal printer on my receipt. I am using [esc_pos_bluetooth](https://pub.dev/packages/esc_pos_bluetooth) package from pub.dev.

I am resizing the image because it may be of any size. so making it suitable for print

In the below function I am getting the image from the network and then converting it into bytes for printing. and simply returning it by resizing.

```
Future<Image.Image> resizeImg(String path) async {
    String imageUrl = 'http://example.co.in/images/$path.png';
    http.Response response = await http.get(imageUrl);
    Uint8List bytes = response.bodyBytes;
    final Image.Image imgs = Image.decodeImage(bytes);
    final Image.Image ig = Image.copyResize(imgs, height: 150, width: 120);
    return ig;
  }
```

and for the print purpose, I am calling `ticket.image` method.

```
final Image.Image img = await resizeImg(data['logo']);
 ticket.image(img);
```

The problem is when the image is printed it's not getting printed correctly. The border of the image is scattered. You can  see it here
[mis printed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUuJU.jpg)

What is the correct way to print an image?. So it will be printed perfectly.

Note: If somebody could explain what can be the possible reasons of not printing correctly it will be really helpful. Sometimes after adjusting image dimensions it worked. but this is not a perfect solution